# Get the my custome math operator from string with RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

I have an string which contains some math calculation like this.

`...12+Ne(10)ConvertTo(Nem) + 9 * 8/7...` which is contain my custome math operator(as in ConvertTo).
ConvertTo operator using like this.Get the Value in the array

`unitData :  [ "Nm","Ne","Nem"]` ,and assign the a number as 10 or what ever else.Later call `ConvertTo` operator with the value in array again.
How can I get the this `Ne(10)ConvertTo(Nem)`  in string.

*in this example Ne and Nem determinated by calculater ,getting this in unitData array
I need to Ne-10 and Nem separatle.

**update**

I need to this pattern `unitDataInArrayWhenKeyPress1(number)ConvertTo(unitDataInArrayWhenKeyPress2)`

each element of the unitData represent button name. and insert the name to calculater screen. 
I need to `unitDataInArrayWhenKeyPress1`-`number` and `unitDataInArrayWhenKeyPress2` separatle.
What I have tried so far is this.

```
//reg=ConvertTo
replaceConvert: function (txt, reg) {

            console.log(txt);
            reg = reg + '\\d';
            console.log(new RegExp(reg, 'g'));
            console.log(txt.match(reg));
            return txt.replace(new RegExp(reg, 'g'));
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the grammar of your math calculator? With the information available, we can only write an overly specific regex for this case only.

Comment: Math calculater language is english

Comment: replaceConvert: function (txt, reg) in here txt only contains pure math oparator exept of the ConvertTo